# For loop through each month of the year using python - pandas

Tags: python, pandas, loops

So I'm using this code but I need a outer for loop to have it running 12 times, for the 12 months of the year and not really sure how I would do that. Any clue?

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas.tseries.offsets import MonthEnd

for beg in pd.date_range('2014-01-01', '2014-06-30', freq='MS'):
    print(beg.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"), (beg + MonthEnd(1)).strftime("%Y-%m-%d"))
```

Comment: Why do you need a loop? What is wrong with your current loop?

Comment: it only prints the current month but i need to run all the 12 months at once

Comment: Still unclear, the example you provide shows **6** different months, not just a single one

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.